# How to redirect reactjs with this.props.history

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';


class box extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      code: '',
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/validateCode', {
      "access code": this.state.code,
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        if(response.status === 200) {
          this.props.history.push("/Treasure");

        }

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);

      });
    event.preventDefault();
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>page 1</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input id="code" type="text" value={this.state.code} onChange={this.handleChange} /> <br></br>
          </label>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

        </form>
      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default box;
```

If I'm given a valid code that gives response status 200 I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

What I want is to redirect me to /Treasure endpoint.

It works for other things for me but not for this I have no idea. If I were to remove the axios bit and click submit then it would redirect me as wanted but for some reason it wont work for this

Comment: Try using arrow functions () => { }  instead of regular functions function () { }, that way you will avoid issues with scope.

With arrow functions you won't need to bind functions in your constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead using an arrow function instead of `function` for the axios response handler to preserve the context of `this`. When using `function() {}` for the handler, `this` no longer refers to the component class, which would prevent you from accessing, `state`, `props`, or similar. An arrow function `() => {}` will help preserve the context of `this`:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  axios.post('http://localhost:8080/validateCode', {
    "access code": this.state.code,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.status === 200) {
        this.props.history.push("/Treasure");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
  handleSubmit = (event)=> {
      axios.post('http://localhost:8080/validateCode', {
        "access code": this.state.code,
      })
        .then( (response) => {
          if(response.status === 200) {
            this.props.history.push("/Treasure");

          }

        })
        .catch( (error) => {
          console.log(error);

        });
      event.preventDefault();
    }
```

change you Function to ES6 ,because (this) instance is not accessible  or you can bind your Function in constructor

```
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
```

Comment: Looks like OP has already done this, the real problem is in the `axios` promise callback

Comment: remove function and make that also ES6 Function